# Sql Query Selecting and if statement

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Im trying to implement a query where by year = bus_year and the yearly period is from april to  the following year in march(12 months)/ (apr -march) Im finding it difficult to run a query whereby when I select bus_year which is year, eg bus_year = 2013, and if I select the month January I should get January 2014 and not 2013.

Database Data used  Id/month/year/bus_year

I tried many options buts its either I get 2013 or can't select a month, Jan, Feb and March should always be the next year but under 2013 bus_year. here are some of the queries I tried.

//

```
public function get($year, $month)
        {

            $bus_year->$select->bus_year;

            $select = $this->select();
            $select->where('bus_year = ?', $year);

            if($month >= 01 && $month <= 03){
            $year = $year + 1;

            return $this->fetchAll($select);
```

//

```
public function get($year)
        {
            $select = $this->select();
            $select->where('bus_year = ?', $year);
            return $this->fetchAll($select);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not worked through a solution as yet, but I see two potential options. Firstly, you could use the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function, assuming MySQL, and then make the query based on two timestamps. Then you wouldn't have to worry about bridging a year.

Secondly, you could convert the months to their numeric equivalents, and if the second is greater than 12, create a query which searches from the start month in the start year and ends with the end month in the next year. I'll write up a solution later and post it.

Comment: Thank you, reading through, unix_timestamp, could be be very useful for the future

Comment: Hi matt , unix timestamp won't work, as unix was implemented recently , so some of the inputs consists no time or date of input

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you'd either have to split your where:

```
WHERE (bus_year = $bus_year AND month between 1 AND 3) OR (bus_year = $bus_year + 1 AND month between 3 AND 12)
```

Or work with MySQL dates and then pass the calculation there:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-04-00 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-00 00:00:00'
```

(I apologize, I did not recognize the ORM therefore I have just pointed out the required where statement and not the whole function. If you direct me towards your ORM \ framework's conventions, I can show you the PHP code, too.)

As far as zend_db_table goes (at least, it seems that way :) ):

For option A:

```
$this->select()->where("bus_year = $bus_year AND month between 1 AND 3")->orWhere("bus_year = $bus_year + 1 AND month between 3 AND 12");
```

For option B:

```
$this->select()->where('date > ?', '2013-04-00')->where('date < ?', '2014-03-00');
```

Comment: Im using zend_db_table

Comment: I am a bit confused with your query, the bus year stays the same. eg 2012/bus_year , Apr to december all under year 2012 which is still bus_year,Jan, Feb and March all under year 2013 but still fall under bus_year 2012...and so on . Not sure if you got me or I am a bit confused

Comment: Could you please specify use cases (including edge cases)?

Comment: Hope that you get me : select periods, where bus_year = bus_year

if bus_year = bus_year || month >= 03){

            $year = $year + 1;
   
   }

Comment: Why do you need the if? the where ensures that bus_year = bus_year

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and sample results. This should make it a little easier to understand.

Comment: The month is one but the year should be the next year, so is for two and three. April to March: period year . These are my firebug results        
year:2013
month:1
submit:Submit

Comment: Man, I'm completely lost. Please update your question with sample data and sample results.

Comment: Please check my current link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328291/query-logic-for-mysql-and-php