# Query Logic For mysql and php

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

we have this company where they work on a yearly period of april"current year" to march"next year"
Im writing and excel report to pull out reports based on that period. where Jan, Feb, and march would be the next year , but I keep on getting the current year do you get me?
bus_year = is the year inform Jan to Dec, but its actually April to march
and year is year

I would like to know how, I could write a good logic whereby on selected months the logic would plus 1 year to the current, from instead of Jan 2013 to Jan 2014. I'm trying to brige years , and could not use unix_timestamp solely because Its just been implemented noe in the database and the is more than 5 year of data in it.

current code

```
 private $month_array  = array(
        '01' => "January",
        '02' => "February",
        '03' => "March",
        '04' => "April",
        '05' => "May",
        '06' => "June",
        '07' => "July",
        '08' => "August",
        '09' => "September",
        '10' => "October",
        '11' => "November",
        '12' => "December"
    );

    private $financial_year_month = array(
        '04' => '01',
        '05' => '02',
        '06' => '03',
        '07' => '04',
        '08' => '05',
        '09' => '06',
        '10' => '07',
        '11' => '08',
        '12' => '09',
        '01' => '10',
        '02' => '11',
        '03' => '12'
    );
```

maybe to right in in a form like this for example

```
04-$year, 05-year, ... , 02-($year+1), 03-($year+1)
```

//sql query
    public function get($year)
            {
                $select = $this->select();
                $select->where('bus_year = ?', $year);
                return $this->fetchAll($select);
            }

Database columns Id/month/year/bus_year

Not sure how I can define and initialize year at the moment. Something like this but my current code wont take it, don't know what Im missing

```
if($month >= 01 && $month <= 03){ $year = $year + 1;
```

Comment: What is the database? Perhaps the best option for this is to put the logic with the database. They have a plethora or date/time functions that will make this easy.

Comment: something like `where datefield BETWEEN now() and now() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR`, assuming mysql?

Comment: Mysql, the problem is for the previous years the was no timestamp..editing my question

Comment: Please check on it again added a couple of sentences on what I want to achieve

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data and desired query results.